# Simultaneously pressing on the ctrl and clicking on the button does not work. Testcafe

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

The  'Delete' button is disabled by default:
`<a class="danger ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only ui-button-disabled ui-state-disabled" id="btn-delete-chassis" role="button" aria-disabled="true"><span class="ui-button-text">Delete</span></a>`
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Only when you press and hold down the ctrl key does the Delete button change to active:
`<a class="danger ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" id="btn-delete-chassis" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Delete</span></a>`

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

But testcafe can't do these steps.

````
await t              
                .click(Selector('#btn-delete-chassis'), { modifiers: { ctrl: true }, speed: 0.05});```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWdFN.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZvID.png
````

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to give you a precise answer without examining an example that demonstrates this implementation. Please create an issue in the testcafe repository using this template: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=TYPE%3A+bug&template=bug_report.yaml

If you don't want to share your real project, please use these recommendations to create a minimal working example: https://testcafe.io/402636/faq#how-to-create-a-minimal-working-example-when-you-submit-an-issue